# New usernames in embeds

Tags: python, pycord

So, I have my bot and I have an /info user command that get some user informations.
and I want to make an "if" if the user has the new username or not. I did that in a /dm command but it's not working on the /info user command.
Here is my code:

````py
@info.command(name="user", description="Mostra informações sobre um usuário")
async def _info(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    if member.discriminator.endswith("0"):
        membro = member.discriminator.strip("#0")
        member = membro
          
    info_embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())
    info_embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.display_avatar})")
    info_embed.add_field(name=":placard: Nome", value=f"```{member}```", inline=True)
    info_embed.add_field(name=":identification_card: Identidade", value=f"```{member.id}```", inline=True)
    info_embed.add_field(name=":link: Menção", value=f"{member.mention}", inline=True)
    created = member.created_at.timestamp()
    info_embed.add_field(name=":calendar_spiral: Conta Criada", value=f'<t:{int(created)}:F> (<t:{int(created)}:R>)', inline=True)
    joined = member.joined_at.timestamp()
    info_embed.add_field(name=":date: Entrou em", value=f'<t:{int(joined)}:F> (<t:{int(joined)}:R>)', inline=False)
    
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=info_embed)
````

There is the error: `discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'discriminator'`

By the way, "info" is a slash command group.

Comment: The member object is not passed to commands.  You have to get that from the context.  The interaction usually comes from there as well.  Is that function actually a class method?

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain it more, please? Thank you!

Comment: The error is saying that the `member` argument was not provided.  That means you have a mismatch.  Is this function actually a method in a class?  Or is it a global-level function?  If it is NOT part of a class, then remove `self` from the list of arguments.  And is your user supposed to provide a username in the command, like `/info xxxuser`?  If the user types a username, then your function will get exactly 2 parameters: a context, and the username.  You're expecting 3 parameters.

Comment: Oh, I get it, it's in a class, it's in a cog.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

````py
@info.command()
async def _info(self, interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    if member.discriminator == "0":
        membro = member.name
    else:
        membro = member
    
    info_embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blurple())
    info_embed.add_field(name=":placard: Nome", value=f"```{membro}```", inline=True)
...
````